# htaccess rewrite rule to trick Server Path to script?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, amazon-s3

I have a PHP photo gallery script that works like this:

```
$image_path        = "../images/11/mycoolphotos/md";
```

If the script and photos are on the same server, then this works perfectly!

However, we just transferred all of our images to Amazon S3 -- so the paths are like this:

```
$image_path        = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebsite/images/11/mycoolphotos/md";
```

But it doesn't work!! It won't read the LIST or Files like the ../ Path ??
I can include a "Order File Path" and it work, but we have 8000 photo galleries! Too much work ?

```
$order_file_path  = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebsite/images/11/mycoolphotos.txt";
// this works, but it would take too much time. This just lists the image names, like 1.jpg, 2.jpg,.. so on for that gallery
```

I am wondering if we trick the server in reading ( not sure how to .htaccess rewrite this )

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebsite/images/
```

as

```
../
```

If it would work ?

Otherwise, I'm not sure where to go from here ?

Thanks much in advance!

EDIT UPDATE: I found the PATH reading function: Can anyone decode this? I tried the suggestions below, but no luck .... ?

```
/**
 * Check for image order file. In case it does not
 * exists, read the image directory.
 */
  if (is_file($order_file_path . '/' . $order_file_name)) {

  $fp  = fopen($order_file_path . '/' . $order_file_name, "r");
    $row = '';
    $use_order_file = 'true';

    while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ';')) {
        $image_data[] = trim($data[0]);
        $image_file_names[trim($data[0])] = trim($data[0]);
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;

        for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) {
            $content_data_temp['field_' . $j] = $data[$j];
        } 

        $content_data[] = $content_data_temp;
        $content_data_temp = '';
    } 
    fclose ($fp);
} else if (is_dir($image_path)) {
    $content_data = '';
    $handle = opendir($image_path);

    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if (preg_match("/^\.{1,2}$/i", $file)) {
            continue;
        } 
        if (preg_match("/\.[a-z]{3}$/i", $file)) {
            $image_data[] = $file;
            $image_file_names[$file] = $file;
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    echo 'Working on older photos, please check back.';
    exit;
} 

$image_number = count ($image_data);
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding the path. Set it as a variable. `$baseurl="http://amazonaws..."`

Comment: hmmm. can you eleborate, i am sort of lost ?

Comment: Don't hard code the path into the path strings. Set the base root as a variable like I said and just reference it like `$image = $baseurl . "/images/..."`. If you don't get that, stop learning PHP now and get a book. Then learn about SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

You could use mod_rewrite in proxy mode for that:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/mywebsite/images/$1 [P]
```

Cheers.

Comment: give it a try - for me this works in related scenarios. Btw. forgot the link to the documentation, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html